# How to build a model for $2 \times 2$ MIMO using GNU Radio?

Tags: gnuradio, mimo

I have been trying to set up a GNU Radio flowgraph where I can implement a $2 \times 2$ MIMO system. don't know how to make spatial diversity using the blocks, also I am not sure which block components I need to use to make this happen. Is there any suggestion for this from you guys? It would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest starting with a more reasonable project, for instance 1x1 DQPSK.

Comment: Hello! I have designed a basic FSK modulation Technique. Btw my goal is to design a 2*2 MIMO where I need to adjust the phase and amplitude of the transmitted signals so that the 2 received signals are in the same phase. Do you have any idea how to do this?